# sql change constraint from unique to normal text

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have created a table and In table i have a column "city" , i did the type of column as Unique ,but now i don't need it as unique . i want to edit it because i want to insert the same name of city but i couldnt do it.
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'istanbul' for key 'ilAdı'
I tried to change it from here but i get this error.
"
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `hotel`.`müşteriler`
;
ALTER TABLE `hotel`.`müşteriler` ALTER INDEX `ilAdı` VISIBLE;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX `ilAdı` VISIBLE' at line 1
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `hotel`.`müşteriler` ALTER INDEX `ilAdı` VISIBLE "

[image: 1]

Comment: You must DROP unneeded unique index from the table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the query for removing the unique key from the column like this:

alter table "your table name" drop index "the name of the column";

the quotations are not need.

this will remove the unique key from the column.